# How to make <td> responsive

Tags: responsive-design, html-table, mailing

I am doing responsive mail and I need to make responsive td in table (without class or using media-query).

Simply - I need on small devices rank the td under them.

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="fff" style="width:100%;  background-color: #fff; max-width:600px;">     
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://www.blahblah.com/"><img src="pic" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="https://blahblah2.com/><img src="pic"  /></a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.blahblah3.com/><img src="pic" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.blahblah4.com/><img src="pic" /></a></td>
  </tr>                                           
</table>
```

Comment: you need responsive table ? Tried inline styling ?

Comment: yes - I need something like display:block; but its not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LgLmxmL6/

Comment: you should use divs then.

Comment: Noo, no divs  I have to use only tables

Comment: try my solution, tried inline-block for every column. It worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

You can try `display:inline-block` for every column in your table. It will make the columns shift below each column when width of the screen decreases.
As you have mentioned that you don't need class so m writing the inline style for each column. Try this code :

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="fff" style="width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff; max-width: 600px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;">
                <p>
                    hellohello</p>
            </td>
            <td style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;">
                <p>
                    hellohello</p>
            </td>
            <td style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;">
                <p>
                    hellohello</p>
            </td>
            <td style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;">
                <p>
                    hellohello</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/LgLmxmL6/1/)

Comment: It works! Only last problem is that now is all <td> on left... http://jsfiddle.net/LgLmxmL6/2/

Comment: where do you want them to be ?

Comment: Fixed - I made tr     text-align: center; :) thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

You can create a media query to force all the td elements to drop below each other at a certain screen width. This ensures they all become vertical-aligned at the same time. It also preserves the table's horizontal-aligned print format if you are generating a report for printing.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    td {
        display:inline-block;
        padding:5px;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```